# Copy rows to new sheet if date in a column range is between two dates decided by user

Tags: vba, excel

I am positively stuck! 
I need to loop in column C of "Raw Data" Sheet till the last row and if the date value is between a starting date and an end date then copy that row to a new sheet "Week". Dates are defined by input box

```
inizio = InputBox("Data Inizio") 'start date
fine = InputBox("Data Fine") 'end date
```

Then 
 I store the last row of the "week" sheet with this formula borrowed from a google search (apology to the author but I cannot remember his/her name)

```
PriRigVuot = Worksheets("Week").Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row
```

and then I run into problems while tring to copy the row that match the If statement

```
For Each cella In Range("c1:c50")
  If Worksheets("Raw Data").Range(cella).Value >= inizio And Worksheets("Raw Data").Range(cella).Value <= fine Then
    Worksheets("Raw Data").Range(cella).EntireRow.Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Week 34").Range("A" & PriRigVuot + 1)
    Else        
    End If
Next Cella
```

I am aware that this code (if it worked at all) would copy the row in the same place  over and over again but I am trying to tackle a step at a time

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, you can store the last row used in sheet `Week` like this:

```
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Week").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

In your `For` loop, you dont need to specify the whole object again, since the `Range` is already specified when you wrote the sentence. So, the code will be like this:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet 
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data")
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Week 34").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cella In sh.Range("C1:C" & sh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) 'Dynamic range in column C
    If cella >= inizio And cella <= fine Then
        cella.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Week 34").Range("A" & LastRow + 1)      
    End If
Next cella
```